# Is there a hook to determine core file generation finished

Tags: linux, core-dump

How I can determine that `core.<pid>` file generation started/finished?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put an [inotify](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inotify) watch in the directory that will contain the core file. Demonstration:

```
/tmp$ { ulimit -c unlimited; exec sleep 9999; } &
[1] 25646
/tmp$ kill -QUIT %1                              
[1]  + 25646 quit (core dumped)  { ulimit -c unlimited; exec sleep 9999; }
```

And in another terminal:

```
$ inotifywait -e close_write /tmp
Setting up watches.
Watches established.
/tmp/ CLOSE_WRITE,CLOSE core
```

That last line, reporting a `CLOSE_WRITE` event, is emitted when the core file is fully written.

Alternatively, Linux lets you customize the generation of core files. This is a system-wide setting and requires root access, so it may or may not suit your scenario. You do this by setting the [`kernel.core_pattern` ioctl](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/core.5.html) to point to a program that will receive the core content on standard output. A toy program could be

```
#!/bin/sh
cat >"/var/cores/$1-$2-$3.core"
# Do whatever you want now that the core file has been written
echo "/var/cores/$1-$2-$3.core" | mail -s "$4 dumped core" denys
```

in `/usr/local/sbin/my_core_dumper`, registered with

```
sysctl kernel.core_pattern='|/usr/local/sbin/my_core_dumper %t %P %e %E'
```

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure if there is "hook"to determine this but, unless it is a OS core dump, it is done in an instant. The moment you see core file, it is finished dumping, in my experience. If something is taking a long time to dump core or any other file for that matter, I usually check the file size in 5 second intervals in a loop and when it has not increased in the 3 or 4 iterations, I can safely assume it is done.

I know this is not what you are looking for but it is a practical workaround, in the lack of another solution.

Comment: No, this is not true. [Linux does not write core dumps atomically](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/254670/is-core-dump-generation-an-atomic-operation).

Comment: It's not instant. If the program is using a lot of memory it's going to take as long as it takes to write that to disk. Which could mean writing a few GB.